# Select MAX() or Select TOP 1 on Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I'm working with the following code to only get  one associated person per case, using the MAX Associated Type to get the top 1.

Associated Type is not a GUID, rather looks like:

Responsible Party, Primary Physician, etc.

It just so happens that Responsible Party is the last alphabetical option, so it's a lucky workaround. Not every case has a responsible party, however, and if there isn't a responsible party, the next top associated person is 'good enough' and will be highlighted as a data error anyway.

The result shows every single associated person (rather than top 1), but shows all of them as Responsible Party, which is not true. What am I doing wrong here?

```
FROM T_LatestIFSP Ltst

LEFT OUTER JOIN ( 
    SELECT
        Clas.ClientCase_ID,
        MAX(Astp.AssociatedType) AS AssociatedType
    FROM
        T_ClientAssociatedPerson Clas
        Inner Join T_AssociatedType Astp
        ON  Clas.AssociatedType_ID = Astp.AssociatedType_ID
    GROUP BY Clas.ClientCase_ID
) AS Astp ON Ltst.ClientCase_ID = Astp.ClientCase_ID


LEFT OUTER JOIN T_ClientAssociatedPerson Clas
    on Clas.ClientCase_ID = Astp.ClientCase_ID


LEFT OUTER JOIN T_AssociatedPerson Aspr
    ON Aspr.AssociatedPerson_ID = Clas.AssociatedPerson_ID
```

[image]

Comment: Should I join subsequent tables on the AssociatedPerson_ID, rather than ClientCase_ID? If so, how to I include AssociatedPerson_ID in the SELECT statement?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih - I just did, thanks.

Comment: Why is the `AssociatedType_ID` for `ClientCase_ID` = '02' in your Expected Results set to `24`? Wouldnt we expect it to be `04`?

Comment: Could you explain more detail on your logic? why did you want to get `MAX` in `AssociatedType`

Comment: AssociatedType_ID is related to the AssociatedType. So Responsible Party is always 16, and there are about 30 other Associated Types. But sorting by AssociatedType_ID does not bring [Responsible Party][16] to the top. Sorting by MAX(AssociatedType) does because, coincidentally, Responsible Party is the last Associated Type, alphabetically.

Comment: @IrenaSagan I add an answer you can try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with the following code:

```
 LEFT OUTER JOIN T_ClientAssociatedPerson Clas
    on Clas.ClientCase_ID = Ltst.ClientCase_ID
    and
        CASE
        WHEN Clas.AssociatedType_ID = 16 AND Clas.ClientCase_ID = Ltst.ClientCase_ID THEN 1
        WHEN Clas.AssociatedType_ID <> 16 AND Clas.AssociatedType_ID = (
            SELECT TOP 1 Clas.AssociatedType_ID
            FROM T_ClientAssociatedPerson Clas
            WHERE Clas.ClientCase_ID  = Ltst.ClientCase_ID
            ORDER BY AssociatedType_ID DESC
        ) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query.

Make `rn` from your `order` condition in `CASE WHEN`

You can use `Rank` with *window function* to make rank number in subquery, then get `rnk=1` data row.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT ClientCase_ID,
          AssociatedPerson_ID,
          AssociatedPersonType,
          AssociatedType_ID,
          RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ClientCase_ID ORDER BY rn desc,AssociatedPerson_ID) rnk
      FROM (
        SELECT t1.ClientCase_ID,
               t1.AssociatedPerson_ID,
               t1.AssociatedPersonType,
               t1.AssociatedType_ID,
                (CASE 
                 WHEN t1.AssociatedPersonType = 'ResPonsible Party'  then 16
                 WHEN t1.AssociatedPersonType = 'Primary Physician'  then 15
                 ELSE 14
                 END) rn
        FROM T t1 
        INNER JOIN T t2 ON t1.ClientCase_ID = t2.AssociatedPerson_ID 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT t2.AssociatedPerson_ID,
               t1.AssociatedPerson_ID,
               t1.AssociatedPersonType,
               t2.AssociatedType_ID,
                (CASE 
                 WHEN t2.AssociatedPersonType = 'ResPonsible Party'  then 16
                 WHEN t2.AssociatedPersonType = 'Primary Physician'  then 15
                 ELSE 14
                 END) rn
        FROM T t1 
        INNER JOIN T t2 ON t1.ClientCase_ID = t2.AssociatedPerson_ID
    ) t1
)
select DISTINCT ClientCase_ID,AssociatedPerson_ID,AssociatedPersonType,AssociatedType_ID
FROM CTE 
WHERE rnk = 1
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e1ab4/3)

---

Also, you can try to use `CROSS APPLY` with value instead of `UNION ALL`

```
;with CTE AS (
SELECT v.*, (CASE 
                 WHEN v.AssociatedPersonType = 'ResPonsible Party'  then 16
                 WHEN v.AssociatedPersonType = 'Primary Physician'  then 15
                 ELSE 14
             END) rn
FROM T t1 
INNER JOIN T t2 ON t1.ClientCase_ID = t2.AssociatedPerson_ID
CROSS APPLY (VALUES 
             (t1.ClientCase_ID,t1.AssociatedPerson_ID,t1.AssociatedPersonType,  t1.AssociatedType_ID),
             (t2.AssociatedPerson_ID,t1.AssociatedPerson_ID,t2.AssociatedPersonType, t2.AssociatedType_ID)
             )  v (ClientCase_ID,AssociatedPerson_ID,AssociatedPersonType,AssociatedType_ID)
)
SELECT distinct ClientCase_ID,AssociatedPerson_ID,AssociatedPersonType,AssociatedType_ID
FROM 
(
  SELECT *, 
         RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ClientCase_ID ORDER BY rn desc,AssociatedPerson_ID) rnk
  FROM CTE
) t1
WHERE rnk = 1
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e1ab4/8)

**Note**

you can add your customer order number in `CASE WHEN`

**[Results]**:

```
| ClientCase_ID | AssociatedPerson_ID | AssociatedPersonType | AssociatedType_ID |
|---------------|---------------------|----------------------|-------------------|
|            01 |                  01 |    ResPonsible Party |                16 |
|            02 |                  03 |  Physician Therapist |                24 |
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your answer helped me reach my own solution.

Answer (score 1):

To get AssocId in the select, you have to do a self join.

LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(your subselect with max(AssociatedType) in it) AS Astp

INNER JOIN T_AssociatedType AS Astp2 
ON (whatever the primary key is on that table)

Then you can add astp2.AssociationTypeId to the original SELECT.

Comment: Thank you for your help.